# Displaying a full post instead of a slug per category?

Tags: categories, links, slug

I have a single category on my blog that I want to display full posts in when looking at the category instead of just slugs.

The category is for Podcasts, and presently it displays slugs which:

- Do not display links to mp3 files
- Do not display the [Google Reader Media Player](https://sites.google.com/site/mori79/html-gadgets/media-players/google-reader-player)

I'm using Wordpress 3.0.4 with the [Hybrid News theme](http://themehybrid.com/themes/hybrid-news).

Answer (score 1):

In the appropriate template file, you need to replace `the_excerpt()` with `the_content()`.

As this is a change specific to a known category (i.e. "podcasts"), I would recommend creating a custom template file for that category, called `category-podcasts.php`, and making the change in that template file.

To create this template file, look for (in order) `category.php`, `archive.php`, or `index.php`. Copy whichever one you find, and rename it as `category-podcasts.php`.

If your Theme is `loop.php`-based, then you will probably want to copy `loop.php` as `loop-podcasts.php`, make the change in this file, and then call it within the `category-podcasts.php` template file.